# How to find the best way to make a SQL query in a stored procedure to be more efficient and fast

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody give me some guidance or advice to improve the query below? It takes almost 2 days to run the job containing the query below.
 The bottleneck is the select query SELECT A.codeA + TrimCode , A.RevisionDate....
The big query is excuted in the middle of a stored procedure
 The big query below is the one that causes a probleme. The job can be completed only after 2 days.
The returned lines result number is 2 millions row.
I have checked the number of rows in both tables below and have figured out why it takes forever to execute the query below:
-- select COUNT(*) FROM CADEAUX.dbo.EI03_VehExtInfo;
-- return 1170454 lines
-- select COUNT(*) FROM CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail ;
-- return 10405145 lines

```
create table #codesTable (
        codeA           char(11),
        TrimCode        char(2),
        RevisionDate    datetime,
        LngCode         char(2),
        );

    create clustered index indx1 on #codesTable (codeA, TrimCode, LngCode)
    create index indx2 on #codesTable (codeA, TrimCode, RevisionDate, LngCode)

    insert into #codesTable (codeA, TrimCode, RevisionDate, LngCode)
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_ModelOpts.dbo.table05_TRIM
    union
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate.dbo.table05_TRIM
    union
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_CHYLR.dbo.table05_TRIM
    union
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_Fleet.dbo.table05_TRIM
    union
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_FCA.dbo.table05_TRIM
    union
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_GCA.dbo.table05_TRIM
    union
    select  substring(codeA,1,11)
            , substring(codeA,12,2)
            , RevisionDate
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_Pre92.dbo.table05_TRIM


    create table #VT51codeAs (
        codeA           char(13),
        LngCode         char(2)
        );

    create clustered index indx1 on #VT51codeAs (codeA, LngCode)

    insert into #VT51codeAs (codeA, LngCode)
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_ModelOpts.dbo.VT51_codeAs
    union
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate.dbo.VT51_codeAs
    union
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_CHYLR.dbo.VT51_codeAs
    union
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_Fleet.dbo.VT51_codeAs
    union
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_FCA.dbo.VT51_codeAs
    union
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_GCA.dbo.VT51_codeAs
    union
    select  codeA
            , LngCode
    from    table_II_Translate_Pre92.dbo.VT51_codeAs

   insert into #EI02 (
          codeA 
        , RevisionDate
        , LngCode
        , ModifiedOn
        , InfoCode
        , ExtInfoVariation 
        , Info1
        , Info2
        , Info3
        , Info4
        , Info5
        , Info6
        , Info7
        , Info8
        , Info9
        , Info10
        , Info11
        , Info12
        , Info13
        , Info14
        , Info15
        , Logic
    )
    SELECT 
          A.codeA + TrimCode
        , A.RevisionDate
        , A.LngCode
        , ISNULL(EI.ModifiedOn,GetDate())
        , EI03.ExtInfoCode
        , EI03.ExtInfoVariation 
        , Column1 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 1 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column2 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 2 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column3 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 3 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column4 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 4 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column5 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 5 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column6 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 6 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column7 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 7 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column8 = substring(isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 8 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),''),1,250)
        , Column9 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 9 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column10 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 10 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column11 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 11 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column12 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 12 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column13 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 13 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column14 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 14 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , Column15 = isnull((SELECT ExtInfoData FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail  WHERE ExtInfoUID = 15 AND codeA = EI03.codeA AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND RevCode = EI03.RevCode),'')
        , EI03.Logic
    FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI03_VehExtInfo EI03 
          inner join [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail EI04 on EI03.codeA = EI04.codeA and ei04.ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode
          and ei04.ExtInfoVariation = ei03.ExtInfoVariation and ei04.RevCode = ei03.RevCode  
          and ei04.ExtInfoUID = 1

        inner join #codesTable A on (
                EI03.codeA = A.codeA 
            AND Deleted = 'F' 
            AND dbo.TrimMatches(A.TrimCode,OptionTrims) = 1
            )
        left join EI_Modified E on (E.codeA = substring(A.codeA,1,11) and E.LngCode = A.LngCode)
        left join ( 
            select  codeA, MAX(ModifiedOn) ModifiedOn from [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.VT12_VehicleModified where  SectionUID in ( 44,45,47,48,49) group by codeA 
            ) EI
            on (EI.codeA = substring(EI03.codeA,1,11))       
    where 
        (
            isnull(E.ModifiedOn,-1) < isnull(EI.ModifiedOn,-1) 
            or 
            A.codeA+A.TrimCode not in (select codeA from EI02_ExtVehInfo EI02 where A.RevisionDate = EI02.RevisionDate and A.LngCode = EI02.LngCode and EI02.InfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode)
            OR
            (   ((E.ModifiedOn = EI.ModifiedOn) AND E.ModifiedOn IS NOt NULL )
                AND 
                ((SELECT Top 1 Info1 FROM EI02_ExtVehInfo EI2 
                WHERE EI2.RevisionDate = A.RevisionDate and EI2.LngCode = A.LngCode and EI2.InfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND EI2.codeA = A.codeA+A.TrimCode) = '')
            )
            OR
            (   ((E.ModifiedOn = EI.ModifiedOn) AND E.ModifiedOn IS NOt NULL )
                AND 
                ((SELECT Top 1 Info1 FROM EI02_ExtVehInfo EI2 
                WHERE EI2.RevisionDate = A.RevisionDate and EI2.LngCode = A.LngCode and EI2.InfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode AND EI2.codeA = A.codeA+A.TrimCode) IS NOT NULL)
            )
            OR exists
                  (
                  select top 1 * from EI02_ExtVehInfo z
                  inner join [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI03_VehExtInfo b on b.codeA = substring(z.codeA,1,11) and b.OptionTrims = substring(z.codeA,12,2) and b.ExtInfoCode = z.InfoCode 
                  inner join [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail c on c.codeA = b.codeA and c.ExtInfoCode = b.ExtInfoCode and b.RevCode = c.RevCode and c.ExtInfoUID = 2 and ExtInfoData = z.Info2 and c.ExtInfoVariation = b.ExtInfoVariation
                  where z.codeA = A.codeA+A.TrimCode and InfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode and LngCode = A.LngCode and Info2 = ei04.ExtInfoData
                  and ((z.Logic is null and b.Logic is not null) OR (z.Logic is not null and b.Logic is null) OR (z.Logic <> b.Logic))
                  )
        ) 


        and 
        EI03.revcode=(
                    SELECT MAX(RevCode) 
                    FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI03_VehExtInfo  
                    WHERE codeA = EI03.codeA 
                    AND ExtInfoCode = EI03.ExtInfoCode 
                    AND ExtInfoVariation = EI03.ExtInfoVariation
                )
```

Comment: Too much chaff.  Not enough wheat.

Comment: Load the temp table with only the clustered index in place and then create the non-clustered index afterward. Use UNION ALL instead of UNION unless you specifically need to remove duplicates. The linked servers could be a killer but it's hard to be specific without a deep dive into the plan and indexes and understand the business purpose of the query.

Comment: @Cindy, as DanGuzman says, the complexity is such that you'd need to post a query plan for all the steps, and a structural description of the tables (including the indexes and how many rows each contain). There are clearly a large number of rows being handled, but 2 days is far beyond the pale.

Comment: You don't seem to be trapping duplicate key or foreign key errors so create the indices after the data is loaded. The ORs are probably killing you. Can you split this up into separate tasks and run in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

@Cindy, bearing in mind my comment, and based on the information available, I'd make some of the following points.

**Firstly**, you're using the moniker `codeA` in an inconsistent way in the code.

In `#codesTable`, it represents the first 11 characters of an underlying field. But then in other places in the code, you re-truncate the field, apparently without purpose. For example, at `(E.codeA = substring(A.codeA,1,11)`, this field in `A` has already been substring-ed to 11 characters.

There are also a multitude of places where you reassemble the values again, for example `(A.codeA + A.TrimCode) NOT IN...`. In doing this, you're creating unnecessary work for the database, confounding the indexes, and you're massively adding to the confusion in the code.

If possible, try and give each a separate name, for example `codeA_short` and `codeA_full`, and store both values in `#codesTable`.

If the database itself is wildly inconsistent in it's meaning of `codeA`, then comment this clearly - and perhaps, create derived tables whose only purpose is to rename the columns of the underlying tables so that their meaning is clearer inside your query. This aliasing will not normally impose any extra burden on the database.

**Secondly**, you're not consistently using two-part names for columns, and it's leaving me guessing (at first glance) as to which tables are being referred to. In a query of this complexity, it's absolutely imperative to be clear. It's also imperative to give tables clearer aliases - using a, b, c, and z, or using no name at all, simply won't do - particularly when you're referring to the same tables multiple times in multiple places, including in subqueries, and many of them share identically named columns.

**Thirdly**, can I suggest a refactoring of the code that fills `#codesTable` like so. This is functionally equivalent but avoids the repetitive substring logic, condenses and makes it a bit more readable in this particular context (you can see what is the same and what differs over each line), and includes my suggestion about storing both the "full" and the "short" codeA columns.

```
INSERT INTO #CodesTable (CodeA_full, CodeA_short, TrimCode, RevisionDate, LngCode)
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CodeA                       AS CodeA_full
        ,SUBSTRING(CodeA, 1, 11)    AS CodeA_short
        ,SUBSTRING(CodeA, 12, 2)    AS TrimCode
        ,RevisionDate           
        ,LngCode
    FROM
        (
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_ModelOpts.dbo.table05_TRIM        UNION ALL
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_Translate.dbo.table05_TRIM        UNION ALL
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_Translate_CHYLR.dbo.table05_TRIM  UNION ALL
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_Translate_Fleet.dbo.table05_TRIM  UNION ALL
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_Translate_FCA.dbo.table05_TRIM    UNION ALL
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_Translate_GCA.dbo.table05_TRIM    UNION ALL
            SELECT CodeA, RevisionDate, LngCode FROM table_II_Translate_Pre92.dbo.table05_TRIM
        ) AS all_a_codes;
```

**Finally**, in your main select, you're performing 15 almost-identical correlated subqueries. In the absence of a query plan I can't be sure, but I would expect this approach to be dire for performance. Consider preparing a pivoted table of data first (I haven't included a final select statement):

```
WITH ei_04_pivot_source AS
(
    SELECT
        CodeA
        ,RevCode
        ,ExtInfoVariation
        ,ExtInfoCode
        ,ExtInfoUID
        ,ExtInfoData 
    FROM [LXXD-TRXI-PLO1].CADEAUX.dbo.EI04_VehExtInfoDetail AS ei_04
)
,ei_04_pivoted_data AS
(
    SELECT * FROM ei_04_pivot_source PIVOT (
        MAX(ExtInfoData)
        FOR ExtInfoUID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15])
    ) AS pvt
)
,ei_04_final_pivot AS
(
    SELECT
        CodeA
        ,RevCode
        ,ExtInfoVariation
        ,ExtInfoCode
        ,ISNULL([1],'') AS Info1
        ,ISNULL([2],'') AS Info2
        ,ISNULL([3],'') AS Info3
        ,ISNULL([4],'') AS Info4
        ,ISNULL([5],'') AS Info5
        ,ISNULL([6],'') AS Info6
        ,ISNULL([7],'') AS Info7
        ,SUBSTRING(ISNULL([8],''),1,250) AS Info8
        ,ISNULL([9],'') AS Info9
        ,ISNULL([10],'') AS Info10
        ,ISNULL([11],'') AS Info11
        ,ISNULL([12],'') AS Info12
        ,ISNULL([13],'') AS Info13
        ,ISNULL([14],'') AS Info14
        ,ISNULL([15],'') AS Info15
    FROM ei_04_pivoted_data
)
```

This can then be left-joined onto the final query, to give you the 15 "Info" columns like so:

```
LEFT JOIN
    ei_04_final_pivot AS ei_04_pd
    ON (ei_04_pd.CodeA = a.CodeA)
    AND (ei_04_pd.RevCode = a.RevCode)
    AND (ei_04_pd.ExtInfoVariation = a.ExtInfoVariation)
    AND (ei_04_pd.ExtInfoCode = a.ExtInfoCode)
```

The ultimate solution to your problem is likely going to involve initially picking the query apart like this, and trying to find out whether there are particular parts that are inherently poorly performing.

The where-clause of the main query is extremely complex and almost unfathomable, especially without an insight into (or any indication of) the function or meaning of it's various parts, and really does need to be substantially refactored.

Comment: is it possible to get the full select statement for the last big hug query?  I would like to try and test your solution but I am not sure I will use it correctly. Thank you. Thank you so much everyone for your reponses.

Comment: @Cindy, it's not a full solution. You'd have to establish whether those subqueries in your select are having a bearing on performance, and how it compares to the performance of the pivot. And that's only the beginning of attempting to rework this query.

Comment: Also, dId you write the main query yourself from scratch? I was assuming you had, and therefore you'd be at a certain level of skill where I can convey ideas to you and you'll be able to implement them. If not, you may be embarking on a task that is beyond your competence - it took me at least an hour, maybe two, just to scrutinise your code and write my answer. I could afford a few hours more overall, but it will be overwhelming if there's not already some shared understanding about how you'd use a with-clause to refactor those subqueries in the select (and this is the easy part so far!).